# Replacing texts with the corresponding column in Excel

Tags: excel, replace, substitution

{

```
"uiComponents":["HOW_TO_BUY"],
"howToBuy": {
    "merchantLogo":"<replace with corresponing column 'img'>",
    "title":"How to buy on <replace with corresponing column 'brand name'> with Company",
    "desktopImgUrl":"<replace with corresponing column 'link'>",
    "actionUrl":"https://www.somewebsite.com/",
    "footerText":"You will be taken to the merchant website in a new tab"
}
```

}

So I have this JSON in one column of excel. There are a few columns namely 'brand name', 'img' and 'link'. I want to replace the entire text that says "replace with corresponding column" with the corresponding column value. Can someone please explain how exactly we do that?

Comment: Use the replace tool. As example, replace `<replace with corresponing column 'brand name'>` with `'brand name'`. [Find or replace text and numbers on a worksheet](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/find-or-replace-text-and-numbers-on-a-worksheet-0e304ca5-ecef-4808-b90f-fdb42f892e90)

Comment: But then it is not like a formula or something right which if we drag down to all the other cells of the JSON, they all will get replaced with the corresponding values? Basically, I need to drag it down and get the text replaced with its corresponding value in the other columns. Thanks!

Comment: You can replace in the **whole** Worksheet if you read the link provided. Anyways, if you want to do it with formulas, check [SUBSTITUTE function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/substitute-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332)

Comment: I checked it, it seems I can only replace with whatever I specify. But each cell has different values in a given column, say 'img' or 'link' 
For say row 1, the corresponding value in column 'img' is X
For row 2, the corresponding value in column 'img' is Y
So accordingly I want to use it instead of doing everything manually.